# How to enter Windows Flip 3D mode on Windows Vista and above?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, desktop, windows-shell

Is it possible to trigger the [`Flip 3D mode`](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-Windows-Flip-3D) on Windows Vista above systems programmatically?
[image]
It is the same as if you manually press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

Comment: I've posted this just for sharing. I don't know the real practical usage of it (even if I like this mode :)

Comment: Note that this feature is gone in Windows 8

Comment: @Deanna, as the whole Aero... From ground back to the trees.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object has the [`WindowSwitcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537749%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method which can invoke this mode.

Here is the Delphi code example:

```
uses
  ComObj;

procedure EnterWindowSwitcherMode;
var
  Shell: OleVariant;
begin
  try
    Shell := CreateOleObject('Shell.Application');
    Shell.WindowSwitcher;
  finally
    Shell := Unassigned;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Win32MajorVersion >= 6 then // are we at least on Windows Vista ?
  begin
    try
      EnterWindowSwitcherMode;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        ShowMessage(E.ClassName + ': ' + E.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

**Update:**

Or as [Norbert Willhelm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/832220/norbert-willhelm) mentioned here, there is also [`IShellDispatch5`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object interface which in fact introduces the [`WindowSwitcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method. So here's another version of the same...

The following piece of code requires the Shell32_TLB.pas unit, which you can in Delphi create this way (note, that you must have at least Windows Vista where the [`IShellDispatch5`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface was used the first time):

- go to menu *Component / Import Component*
- continue with selected *Import a Type Library*
- select *Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation* and finish the wizard

And the code:

```
uses
  Shell32_TLB;

procedure EnterWindowSwitcherMode;
var
  // on Windows Vista and Windows 7 (at this time :)
  // is Shell declared as IShellDispatch5 object interface
  AShell: Shell;
begin
  try
    AShell := CoShell.Create;
    AShell.WindowSwitcher;
  finally
    AShell := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: There is also IShellDispatch5.